# Where can i see the output of DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE() in IBM Data Studio?

Tags: database, db2, ibm-data-studio

I am using IBM Data Studio as Development environment,

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST()
 is
 BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE("Hi there.");
 END;
```

I can see in execution details like time, exception if any, other info in  `SQL Results window`.
Is IBM studio is storing OUTPUT details in some file ? If so than i would like to know location.

How can enable this feature witch can provide this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to see the output in Data Studio (I think this is more related to how Eclipse deals with stdout). The DBMS_OUTPUT is for console only. As explained in [DBMS_OUTPUT](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0053551.html), these messages are put in the "message buffer" which at the end of the executing is sent to the standard output.

If you want to write messages like a log, I recommend to use a logger system like [log4db2](https://github.com/angoca/log4db2) instead of using DBMS_OUTPUT built-in module.

Comment: This has nothing to do with stdout, obviously. `DBMS_OUTPUT` is intended to be used in CLP and CLPPlus scripts.

Comment: From the DB2 Official documentation: "These procedures are useful during application debugging when you need to write messages to standard output"

Comment: What does "standard output" mean in this case?

Comment: CLP and CLPPlus retrieve messages from the message buffer (which is simply an array of strings defined in the `DBMS_OUTPUT` module) and, being console applications, print them to the only medium available to them -- standard output. So, `DBMS_OUTPUT` does not have any access to, or knowledge of, stdout; CLP and CLPPlus do.